# fallback sshd_config script

Tags: ssh, sshd

Is there a way to run a script such as:

```
cp /etc/ssh/sshd_config.orginal /etc/ssh/sshd_config
reboot
```

if my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` fails?

---

### Why do I need this?

Well sometimes when I edit the file it causes me to not be able to get ssh connection to my root user on my computer. Which is a **huge** issue as I am 200 miles away from my computer!

---

Currently when I am editing the file I turn a cron on:

```
*/10 * * * * /usr/bin/ssh_replace.sh
```

which runs the script above but that is very stressful as I have to turn it off when I have finished and on when I want to start editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the method you already use is the only one that's really working. The main problem is that if the ssh daemon config is failing how is the server supposed to know that it is failing?
 In theory you can write a script that replaces the faulty config with a correct backup version but this is only useful if the server can detect the configuration is failing, For example if the ssh daemon crashes then the process is gone which can be sign it is time to put the backup in place.
However you can make adjustments that negatively affect ssh connectivity while the daemon still remains active. This is something you can't detect and therefore the backup will not be copied.

Answer (score 0):

SSH is started using Upstart, and uses Upstart's [`respawn`](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#respawn) option to restart it when the process dies. Therefore you can try detecting when the SSH job has [hit the respawn limit](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#detecting-a-job-hitting-its-respawn-limit), and overwrite the configuration with a known-good one. For example:

```
# cat /etc/init/ssh-safe.conf
start on stopped ssh RESULT="failed" PROCESS="respawn"
script
  cp /etc/ssh/sshd_config.original /etc/ssh/sshd_config
  start ssh RESTARTED_BY_WATCHDOG=1 || true
end-script
```